# Получаю Permission denied при запуске composer из Docker, как исправить?

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose, composer

Есть Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 - свежая установка, поставил Docker Desktop для удобства управления контейнерами (хотя уже сомневаюсь в этом, т.к. через консоль все стараюсь делать).

Создал 3 контейнера для проекта:

1. Nginx
2. PHP-FMP
3. PHP-CLI

В Dockerfile PHP-CLI указываю следующее

```
FROM php:8.2-cli-alpine

RUN mv $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini

RUN addgroup -g 1000 app && adduser -u 1000 -G app -s /bin/sh -D app

COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app

USER app
```

Когда происходит установка зависимостей, выпадает ошибка

```
file_put_contents(./composer.json): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Права на папку на локальном компе, которую я монтирую в образ 775, когда меняю на 777 все работает норм, composer спокойно запускается из докера и устанавливаются зависимости. Подскажи пожалуйста почему создаваемый юзер в докере не может писать в папку с моим проектом без установления прав 777 на эту папку? Хочу понять этот момент с правами.

Comment: а в системе один юзер ? 
Ну или так. `id -u` если наберете, то  выдаст 1000 ?

Comment: ну или покажите ls -n ./composer.json

Comment: @zalex в системе один юзер, вывод команды id -u отображает 1000, на вывод команды ls -n ./composer.json результат следующий
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 836 ноя 17 09:39 ./composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была сугубо в правах каталога, где лежит мой проект, т.е. эту папку я монтирую в Docker. Так как права на папку были 775 соответственно пользователь из Docker используя php-cli не мог писать в эту папку что-либо, если меняем права на 773 (т.е. позволяем остальным юзерам писать в папку и производить запуск файлов) - все начинает работать. Из-за того, что я работаю на локальной машине и кроме меня никого на ней нет, решил выставить права 777 на каталог где лежим мой проект.